# Link against a library via a remote connection(ROS net)

Tags: ros, package, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have already learn how to link against  a package with your help. Now, I need to link  against a package via ROS Network. To be clear, I have to PCs, A and B. In A (as a master) I create a catkin package including my main node and in B (as a host)I have a repository/Lib. I need to link against the repository located in B from catkin package in A via ROS network. Now I wonder if it is possible or not? if it is, what kind of changes must be applied to CMakeLists.txt and package.xml? Is adding the repository to find_package and catkin_package still applicable?

I appreciate it if you help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200010/link-against-a-library-via-a-remote-connection(ros-net)/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This cannot be done.

Instead, you should put the source code for your library package in source control, and have it checked out on both machines. That way, any packages which use it can link against the copy which is on the local machine.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-24**:
Thanks. But I don't understand your first sentence. Would you please expand on it?